# How do I write a GitHub Action so code is only pulled in the first job and is referenced in later jobs

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am working with GitHub Actions and am attempting to create GitHub Pipeline that deploy terraform to AWS and pushes docker containers. The only thing is that I want to see if it is possible to only checkout the code in the first job for terraform and docker jobs to reference later. All I know is that I would have the `needs` flag for job running dependency, but how do I have the code pulled once in the first job and then just referenced future jobs?

Below is the code that I have so far

```
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code and set up environment
        id: get_code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Other setup job steps here

  deploy_docker:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # steps written after here
```

Comment: Each job gets its own fresh virtual environment, so no, nothing persists between jobs unless you transfer artifacts around (see https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/19). The only way I know to actually share the checkout is to combine things as subsequent steps in the same job instead of making different jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with using artifacts. Uploaded the artifact in the first job and then downloaded the artifact all jobs following. Example:

```
jobs:
   setup:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout code
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
  
          - name: Artifact Code
            uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
            with:
              name: code
              path: .

          - name: Set up AWS CLI
            uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
            with:
                aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
                aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
                aws-region: us-east-1

          - name: Login to Amazon ECR
           id: login-ecr
           uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
    deploy_docker:
        needs: setup
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Download Code
              id: download_code
              uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
              with:
              name: code

  # more steps follow this
```